# c, loading dynamic array from saved file but cannot change anything in that array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, malloc, realloc

Im trying to create a student database using dynamic arrays for a task from c programming course (Just c, not c++ or c#). One thing that this program should be able to do is to save the dynamic array that contains all the student and their information and then you should be able to load that file back again. I'm able to save and load a file with this dynamic arrray and check through the array to see all the students and their information that are inside it, but I can't add or delete memory in that array. So it's impossible for me to add another student or delete one from a saved file that I have loaded.

Here is my entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


struct student {

    long long int persnum;
    char name[50];
    char gender[10];
    char program[50];
    int age;
    char email[100];
};

struct student *y = NULL;



struct program {
    char prgName[50];
    int prgStudents;
    int prgFemales;
    int prgMales;
    int prgTotAge;
    int prgAvgAge;

};

struct program *prg = NULL;

int main() {

    int x = 0, n_s = 0;
    char ans;

    while (x != 7) {

        printf("1. Add\n2. Modify\n3. Delete\n4. Search\n5. Save\n6. Load\n7. Exit\n");

        scanf("%d", &x);
        getchar();

        if (x == 1)
            addPers(&n_s);


        else if (x == 2)
            modifyStud(&n_s);


        else if (x == 3)
            delStud(&n_s);


        else if (x == 4)
            searchStud(&n_s);

        else if (x == 5)
            saveStud(&n_s);

        else if (x == 6)
            loadStud(&n_s);
    }


    printf("Do you wanna save before quiting (y/n)?\n");
    scanf("%c", &ans);
    getchar();

    if (ans == "Y" || ans == "y") {
        saveStud(&n_s);
        system("pause");
    }
}

int addPers(int* n_sPtr) {


    if (*n_sPtr == 0)
    {
        y = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
        if (y == NULL) {

            printf("Could not allocate memory.");

            exit(1);
        }
    }


    else if (*n_sPtr > 0) {
        y = realloc(y, sizeof(struct student)*(*n_sPtr + 1));
    }

    printf("Name: ");
    fgets(y[*n_sPtr].name, 50, stdin);

    printf("Personal number(yymmddxxxx): ");
    scanf("%jd", &y[*n_sPtr].persnum);
    getchar();

    printf("Gender: ");
    fgets(y[*n_sPtr].gender, 10, stdin);

    printf("Age: ");
    scanf("%d", &y[*n_sPtr].age);
    getchar();

    printf("Study progam: ");
    fgets(y[*n_sPtr].program, 10, stdin);

    printf("Email address: ");
    fgets(y[*n_sPtr].email, 100, stdin);

    *n_sPtr += 1;
}

int modifyStud(int* n_sPtr) {
    int j, found = 0;
    long long int searchnum;

    printf("Personal number of the person you want to modify (yymmddxxxx): ");
    scanf("%jd", &searchnum);
    getchar();

    for (j = 0; j < *n_sPtr; j++) {

        if (y[j].persnum == searchnum) {

            printf("New name: ");
            fgets(y[j].name, 50, stdin);

            printf("New gender: ");
            fgets(y[j].gender, 10, stdin);

            printf("New age: ");
            scanf("%d", &y[j].age);
            getchar();

            printf("New study progam: ");
            fgets(y[j].program, 10, stdin);

            printf("New email address: "),
            fgets(y[j].email, 100, stdin);

            found = 1;
        }
    }

    if (found == 0)
        printf("Could not find student.\n");
}

int delStud(int* n_sPtr) {

    int j, found = 0;
    long long int searchnum;


    printf("Personal number of the person you want to delete from database: ");
    scanf("%jd", &searchnum);
    getchar();

    for (j = 0; j < *n_sPtr; j++) {

        if (y[j].persnum == searchnum) {
            free(&y[j]);
            found = 1;
            *n_sPtr -= 1;
        }
    }

    if (found == 0) {
        printf("Could not find student.\n");
    }

    else {
        printf("Student Deleted.\n");
    }

}

int searchStud(int* n_sPtr) {

    int x2, j, found = 0;

    printf("1. Personal number\n2. Name \n3. Study program \n4. Statistics\n");
    scanf("%d", &x2);
    getchar();

    if (x2 < 4) {

        if (x2 == 1) {

            long long int searchnum;

            printf("Enter Personal number of the person you want to find (yymmddxxxx): ");
            scanf("%jd", &searchnum);
            getchar();

            for (j = 0; j < *n_sPtr; j++) {

                if (y[j].persnum == searchnum) {

                    printf("\nPersonal nummber: %jd\nName: %sGender: %sStudy program: %sAge: %d\nEmail: %s\n", y[j].persnum, y[j].name, y[j].gender, y[j].program, y[j].age, y[j].email);

                    found = 1;
                }
            }

        }

        if (x2 == 2) {

            char searchname[50];

            printf("Enter full name of the person you want to find: ");
            fgets(searchname, 50, stdin);


            for (j = 0; j < *n_sPtr; j++) {

                if (strcmp(y[j].name, searchname) == 0) {

                    printf("\nPersonal nummber: %jd\nName: %sGender: %sStudy program: %sAge: %d\nEmail: %s\n", y[j].persnum, y[j].name, y[j].gender, y[j].program, y[j].age, y[j].email);

                    found = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        if (x2 == 3) {

            char searchprogram[50];

            printf("Enter the study program of the person you want to find: ");
            fgets(searchprogram, 50, stdin);


            for (j = 0; j < *n_sPtr; j++) {

                if (strcmp(y[j].program, searchprogram) == 0){

                    printf("\nPersonal nummber: %jd\nName: %sGender: %sStudy program: %sAge: %d\nEmail: %s\n", y[j].persnum, y[j].name, y[j].gender, y[j].program, y[j].age, y[j].email);

                    found = 1;
                }
            }

        }

        if (found == 0)
            printf("Could not find student.\n");
    }


    if (x2 == 4) {

        int males = 0, females = 0, ageamn = 0, ageavg = 0, n_p = 0, newFound, i, k, l, h, t;

        for (j = 0; j < *n_sPtr; j++) {

            if (strcmp(y[j].gender, "f\n") == 0 || strcmp(y[j].gender, "F\n") == 0) {
                females += 1;
            }

            else if (strcmp(y[j].gender, "m\n") == 0 || strcmp(y[j].gender, "M\n") == 0) {
                males += 1;
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < *n_sPtr; i++) {
            ageamn += y[i].age;
        }

        ageavg = ageamn / *n_sPtr;


        for (k = 0; k < *n_sPtr; k++) {

            if (n_p == 0) {
                prg = malloc(sizeof(struct program));
                if (prg == NULL) {
                    printf("Could not allocate memory.");
                    exit(1);
                }
                prg[0].prgMales = 0;
                prg[0].prgFemales = 0;
                prg[0].prgStudents = 0;
                prg[0].prgTotAge = 0;
                n_p += 1;

                strcpy(prg[0].prgName, y[k].program);


                if (strcmp(y[k].gender, "m\n") == 0 || strcmp(y[k].gender, "M\n") == 0) {
                    prg[0].prgMales += 1;
                    prg[0].prgStudents += 1;
                }

                else if (strcmp(y[k].gender, "f\n") == 0 || strcmp(y[k].gender, "F\n") == 0) {
                    prg[0].prgFemales += 1;
                    prg[0].prgStudents += 1;
                }

                prg[0].prgTotAge += y[k].age;
            }

            else if (n_p > 0) {

                newFound == 0;

                for (l = 0; l < n_p; l++) {

                    if (strcmp(y[k].program, prg[l].prgName) == 0) {

                        if (strcmp(y[k].gender, "m\n") == 0 || strcmp(y[k].gender, "M\n") == 0) {
                            prg[l].prgMales += 1;
                            prg[l].prgStudents += 1;
                        }

                        else if (strcmp(y[k].gender, "f\n") == 0 || strcmp(y[k].gender, "F\n") == 0) {
                            prg[l].prgFemales += 1;
                            prg[l].prgStudents += 1;
                        }

                        prg[l].prgTotAge += y[k].age;
                    }

                    else {
                        newFound = 1;
                    }

                }


                if (newFound == 1) {

                    prg = realloc(prg, sizeof(struct program)*(n_p + 1));

                    prg[l].prgMales = 0;
                    prg[l].prgFemales = 0;
                    prg[l].prgStudents = 0;
                    prg[l].prgTotAge = 0;
                    n_p += 1;

                    strcpy(prg[l].prgName, y[k].program);


                    if (strcmp(y[k].gender, "m\n") == 0 || strcmp(y[k].gender, "M\n") == 0) {
                        prg[l].prgMales += 1;
                        prg[l].prgStudents += 1;
                    }

                    else if (strcmp(y[k].gender, "f\n") == 0 || strcmp(y[k].gender, "F\n") == 0) {
                        prg[l].prgFemales += 1;
                        prg[l].prgStudents += 1;
                    }

                    prg[l].prgTotAge += y[k].age;

                    newFound = 0;
                }


            }
        }

        for (t = 0; t < n_p; t++) {

            prg[t].prgAvgAge = prg[t].prgTotAge / prg[t].prgStudents;
        }

        printf("Amount of students: %d\nAmount of female students: %d\nAmount of male students: %d\nAvarage age for all students: %d\n", *n_sPtr, females, males, ageavg);

        for (h = 0; h < n_p; h++) {

            printf("\nProgram: %sAmount of female students: %d\nAmount of male students: %d\nAvarage age for all students: %d\n", prg[h].prgName, prg[h].prgFemales, prg[h].prgMales, prg[h].prgAvgAge);

        }
    }
}

int saveStud(int* n_sPtr) {
    int j;

    FILE *db = fopen("students.dat", "wb");
    if (db == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fwrite(y, sizeof(struct student), *n_sPtr, db);

    fclose(db);

    printf("Students succesfully saved.\n");
}

int loadStud(int* n_sPtr) {
    long filesize;

    FILE *db = fopen("students.dat", "rb");
    if (db == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fseek(db, 0, SEEK_END);
    filesize = ftell(db);
    rewind(db);

    y = malloc(sizeof(filesize));
    if (y == NULL) {
        printf("Could not allocate memory.\n");
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    *n_sPtr = filesize / sizeof(struct student);

    if (fread(y, sizeof(struct student), *n_sPtr, db) == 0) {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    else {
        printf("Students succesfully loaded.\n");
    }
}
```

I have no idea why it dosen't work, any help is appreciated. I'm supposed to turn this in very soon so I really need some help fast.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [***Minimal***, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `free(&y[j]);` Since you allocate all students as one big block of memory (with `malloc` and `realloc`), you can't delete an individual one like that. You need to shift all elements of the array after the one to delete back one. Then call `realloc` with size - 1.

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile!  Amongst many other problems, it is missing this statement: `#include <string.h>` which exposes the function: `strcpy()`

Comment: variable and parameter names should indicate `content` or `usage`.  Names like: `'h', 'n_p', 't', 'n_sPtr', 'y'. 'x2'. etc are meaningless, even in the current context.

Comment: when calling function like: `fgets()`, 'scanf()`, etc always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%jd", &y[*n_sPtr].persnum);`  that format specifier is expecting an argument type 'intmax_t' but the argument has type: `long long int *`.   When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`,at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 10, 50, 100.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those magic numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the series of `if/elseif` code blocks, following: `scanf("%d", &x);
        getchar();` would be much better written as a `switch()` statement with cases, including a `default:` case.  The current code is expecting the user to always enter a valid value!  Never trust the user to do the right thing, even if that user is yourself.

Comment: several of the posted functions have a return type other than `void` but do no have a `return value;` statement at the end of every execution path.

Comment: regarding: `if (ans == "Y" || ans == "y") {`  the double quotes is making `y` and `Y` into strings.  so this statement is comparing a char with a pointer (twice)  Suggest: `if (ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y') {`

Comment: regarding (about line 3) : `else if (x == 3)
            delStud(&n_s);`   The function body for `delStud()` is declared after this call, so the compiler will out a message about a 'implicit function definition'.   Suggest inserting `prototype` statements, near the top of the code, for each of the sub functions.

Comment: why the double spacing between code blocks but only single spacing between functions?  for readability, it should be the other way around

Comment: regarding: `y = realloc(y, sizeof(struct student)*(*n_sPtr + 1));`  When calling `realloc()`, always assign the result to a temporary pointer, check that pointer for NULL, and if not NULL, then assign to the target pointer.  Otherwise, when the function fails, the original pointer is lost, resulting in a memory leak.  Not checking the result for NULL results in accessing memory near address 0, resulting in a seg fault event

Comment: regarding: `printf("Could not allocate memory.");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  When outputting a error message from a system function (other than the `scanf()` family of functions) call `perror()` as that will output your text and the text that describes what the system thinks is the cause of the error, to `stderr`

Comment: when calling `fgets()` the whole input is placed in the input buffer, including any trailing 'newline'  So should always check the input buffer for a '\n' and if found, replace with a '\0'.

Comment: regarding: (about line 180) `scanf("%d", &x2);`  this allows the user to input negative numbers.   regarding the following code: a -2 would be less than 4.  What happens if the user inputs: 5?

Comment: when calling `fseek()` and/or `ftell()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: `y = malloc(sizeof(filesize));`  this will allocate 4 (or 8) bytes, depending on the underlying architecture.  Probably not what you want.

Comment: regarding: `if (fread(y, sizeof(struct student), *n_sPtr, db) == 0) {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");`  The problem is NOT that  the file did not open.  Also, the comparison for the call to `fread()` should be the same as the third parameters, not 0

Comment: it is best to honor the printed page, right margin, (usually 72 or 80) so this line: `printf("1. Add\n2. Modify\n3. Delete\n4. Search\n5. Save\n6. Load\n7. Exit\n");`  would be much better written as: `printf("1. Add\n" <newline> "2. Modify\n" <newline> "3. Delete\n" <newline> "4. Search\n" <newline> "5. Save\n" <newline> "6. Load\n" <newline> "7. Exit\n");

Comment: Note: the heap allocation function: ( malloc, calloc, realloc ) expect a parameter type of `size_t` not `int`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: insert an appropriate horizontal space:  inside parens, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators.

Comment: it is good programming practice to limit the scope of variables when ever possible.  As a 'for instance', in function: `modifyStud()` this statement: `for (j = 0; j < *n_sPtr; j++) {` would be much better written as: `for ( int j = 0; j < *n_sPtr; j++ ) {` and remove the previous declaration of the variable `j`

Comment: there are LOTS more problems with the posted code, but the above comments should point you in the right direction